# Some Random variables proofs.

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

1) I've 2 random variables X ~ Bin(n,p), Y ~Bin(n, 1-p)
Now I need to show that Fx(i) = 1 - Fy(n-i-1) where F is the normal binome distribution. Now I've tried just putting i and I get that Fy(n-i-1) = Fx(i+1) and beats me how Fx(i) + Fx(i+1) = 1.

2) I need to find a $\lambda$ so that Fx(k) is maximal for X ~ Poi($\lambda$) meaning the poissan distribution.

Thank you!

Comment: Note that binomial distributions are discrete, and that $F(i)$ is a probability of ${0,1,2,3,...,i}$ with $ i$ included.

Comment: Thanks for the reply although I don't see how that helps me, since F(i) is the probabilty of 0,1,2,3,..i and F(i+1) is 0,1,2,3,4,...i+1 how exactly do their sum is 1?

Comment: $1 - Fy(n-i-1) = Fx(i)$, because of the weak inequality. $Fx(i) = Bin(n,p) [0,i]= Bin(n,1-p) [n,n-i]$

Comment: Okay thanks! got it.

Answer (score 0):

Try learning a bit of [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) before posting questions on this website.

Concerning your first question: 
It is simpler than you think. Just move the CDF expression of the random variable $Y$ to the other side of the equation. Once they are on the same side write both functions [explicitely as sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function). Open the two sigma expressions and observe the addend components within. Does this overall sum look familiar to you?

HINT: How about [now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement)?